# Можно одновременно обустраивать и закладывать что-либо на этом месте?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Здесь запечатлен папа Феликс IV, который **обустраивает языческий
>   мавзолей, закладывает на его месте христианскую церковь и украшает
>   её**.

Comment: Был язычником — обустроил мавзолей, стал папой — разрушил, заложил церковь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Здесь запечатлен папа Феликс IV, который создает христианскую церковь на месте древних зданий языческого храма и украшает её.**

**Еще вариант:** Здесь запечатлен папа Феликс IV, который создает христианскую церковь **из древних зданий** языческого храма и украшает её.

Папа Феликс IV (526-530) **перестраивает языческий храм Ромула**, делая его преддверием церкви Космы и Дамиана. Сама же церковь расположилась на месте библиотеки, которую построил на Форуме император Веспасиан. Два здания стали одним, а огромные бронзовые двери ромуловского храма теперь служили порталом. В 5-м веке также отстроили храм Сатурна, который также имел колонны по типу греческих.
http://slovoopolku.ru/?item=2b998735-23eb-4372-95b6-313776bec1c5&termin=133e11ae-f1bd-4433-8dbe-15a324a27b47

Описание церкви:
*Церковь, построенная Феликсом IV, **состояла из трех древних зданий...***
http://rulibs.com/ru_zar/sci_history/gregorovius/0/j155.html

Comment: Jasmin, напишите книгу — у Вас и содержание, и форма будут в порядке!

Comment: Форма — да, а вот с содержанием проблемы. Где взять "огонь, мерцающий в сосуде"?

Answer (score 2):

Предположу, что подразумевалось такое:

Здесь запечатлен папа Феликс IV, который **перестраивает** языческий мавзолей, закладывает на его месте христианскую церковь и украшает её.

Тоже не шедевр, но не полная чушь.

Comment: Именно *перестройку* я и отправила автору. С вопросом. Может, просто недоговорено чего-нито.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что отдельно, но не исключаю, что на одном формате — три одноимённых папы.

*Здесь, в отдельных клеймах, запечатлён папа Феликс IV: он обустраивает языческий мавзолей, закладывает на его месте христианскую церковь и украшает её.*

Comment: И обратно змий: *три одноимённых папы.*...